# Ember testing: Visiting external URL for integration test

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I'm helping redo a site that currently exists. One of the tests I'm trying to run is make sure that when I run a search on the old site I get the same results on the same search on the new site.

Is there a way to programmatically visit the old site and run a query?

When I try and use the Ember test helper `visit` it's trying to go to a route for the app. Not to an external URL.

Is this possible in a test?

Thanks!